# Scroll indicator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use the following code for a scroll indicator which I include on multiple pages.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedBar">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But some of the pages are not able to scroll due to lack of content I am trying to get the scroll indicator to also be filled I can't figure out why it's not filling if it cant scroll ( I am not good with JavaScript either :3 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- Execute your function at least once when the page is loaded
- Check if document has no scroll and set full width in that case.

Here it is:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function () {
    myFunction()
};

// Execute myFunction once when the page is loaded
window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
    var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrolled = 100; // Default value: fill width

    // Only if document is scrollable
    if (height > 0) {
        scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    }
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.header h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 0%;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Scroll Down to See The Effect</h3>
  <p>We have created a "progress bar" to <b>show how far a page has been scrolled</b>.</p>
  <p>It also <b>works when you scroll back up</b>.</p>
  <p>It is even <b>responsive</b>! Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

(Found it on W3Schools!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.progress-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 8px;
        background: #ccc;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    .progress-bar {
        height: 8px;
        background: #4caf50;
        width: 0%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="fixedBar">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="progress-container">
                <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script>

         window.onload = function () {
             if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight === document.documentElement.clientHeight){
                 document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = "100%";
             }
         };

        // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
        window.onscroll = function () {
            myFunction()
        };
    
        function myFunction() {
            var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
            document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant't divide by zero
try this

```js
function myFunction() {
            var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            var scrolled = height !== 0 ? (winScroll / height) * 100 : 0;
            document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is due to the lack of a check of the height of the docuement and the client's window height. Yo can solve it like this:

```
    let heightClient = window.innerHeight;
    let body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    let heightDocument = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

    if(heightClient < heightDocument){
        window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
    }else document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = "100%";

    function myFunction() {
        let winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        let height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        let scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
        document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
    }
</script>
```