# Add horizontal scroll indicator to DIV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I want to show an horizontal scroll indicator for a scrollable DIV container.

After some testing I'm pretty sure that it's not possible wit pure CSS.
I found a snippet in an [answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53296181/1788961).
Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to change the script to my needs.

I'm using a simple DIV container with some elements in it.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
        <div class="scroll-container">
            <ul class="list-inline text-white text-center">
            
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 200px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">1</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 400px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">2</h1></div>
                </li>
                [....]
            
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll-indicator">
        <div class="scroll-indicator-bar"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <button>Prev</button>
        <button>Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.scroll-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.scroll-indicator {height: 4px; width: 100%; background-color: #ddd; margin-bottom: 2rem;}

.scroll-indicator-bar {height: 4px; width: 20%; background-color: #000;}
```

**[Working example](https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/MWjLPqp)**

Is there any way to animate the scrollbar indicator with CSS and/or jQuery?

EDIT: I found another good example here: **https://codepen.io/mahish/pen/RajmQw**

I tried to use the code in my example but the prev/next buttons doesn't work. And I also don't know how to use the scroll position to show and move a scroll indicator.

Here's the JS code from the example (change to my class names):

```
// duration of scroll animation
var scrollDuration = 300;
// paddles
var leftPaddle = document.getElementsByClassName('left-paddle');
var rightPaddle = document.getElementsByClassName('right-paddle');
// get items dimensions
var itemsLength = $('.item').length;
var itemSize = $('.item').outerWidth(true);
// get some relevant size for the paddle triggering point
var paddleMargin = 20;

// get wrapper width
var getMenuWrapperSize = function() {
    return $('.scroll-wrapper').outerWidth();
}
var menuWrapperSize = getMenuWrapperSize();
// the wrapper is responsive
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    menuWrapperSize = getMenuWrapperSize();
});
// size of the visible part of the menu is equal as the wrapper size 
var menuVisibleSize = menuWrapperSize;

// get total width of all menu items
var getMenuSize = function() {
    return itemsLength * itemSize;
};
var menuSize = getMenuSize();
// get how much of menu is invisible
var menuInvisibleSize = menuSize - menuWrapperSize;

// get how much have we scrolled to the left
var getMenuPosition = function() {
    return $('.scroll-container').scrollLeft();
};

// finally, what happens when we are actually scrolling the menu
$('.scroll-container').on('scroll', function() {

    // get how much of menu is invisible
    menuInvisibleSize = menuSize - menuWrapperSize;
    // get how much have we scrolled so far
    var menuPosition = getMenuPosition();

    var menuEndOffset = menuInvisibleSize - paddleMargin;

    // show & hide the paddles 
    // depending on scroll position
    if (menuPosition <= paddleMargin) {
        $(leftPaddle).addClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    } else if (menuPosition < menuEndOffset) {
        // show both paddles in the middle
        $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    } else if (menuPosition >= menuEndOffset) {
        $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).addClass('hidden');
}

    // print important values
    $('#print-wrapper-size span').text(menuWrapperSize);
    $('#print-menu-size span').text(menuSize);
    $('#print-menu-invisible-size span').text(menuInvisibleSize);
    $('#print-menu-position span').text(menuPosition);

});

// scroll to left
$(rightPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.scroll-container').animate( { scrollLeft: menuInvisibleSize}, scrollDuration);
});

// scroll to right
$(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.scroll-container').animate( { scrollLeft: '0' }, scrollDuration);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using SimpleBar: https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar

Answer (score 1):

You can have your own custom horizontal scroll behavior with vanilla js, you just need to handle `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove` events, calculate the needed scroll value and move your elements using `transform: translateX()` style, and to keep track with these values,

I did some changes and added some js code, check the snippet bellow:

```js
const scrollBar = document.getElementById('myBar');
const scrollBarWrapper = document.getElementById('barWrapper');
const scrollContent = document.getElementById('scroll-container');

scrollBar.style.width =  ((scrollContent.offsetWidth * scrollBarWrapper.offsetWidth) / scrollContent.scrollWidth) + 'px';

let isScrolling = false;
let cursorX = 0;
let translateXValue = 0;

scrollBar.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isScrolling = true;
    cursorX = e.clientX;
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (isScrolling) {
        e.preventDefault();
        isScrolling = false;
        translateXValue += (e.clientX - cursorX);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (isScrolling && cursorX !== e.clientX) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const translateAmount = (translateXValue + (e.clientX - cursorX));
        const scrollLength = (barWrapper.offsetWidth - scrollBar.offsetWidth);
        const barScroll = Math.min(Math.max(0, translateAmount), scrollLength);
        const contentTranslateRatio = (barScroll * scrollContent.scrollWidth) / scrollContent.offsetWidth;
        
        scrollBar.style.transform = 'translateX(' + barScroll + 'px)';
        scrollContent.style.transform = 'translateX(' + -contentTranslateRatio + 'px)';
    }
});
```

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.scroll-indicator {height: 6px; width: 100%; background-color: #ddd; margin-bottom: 2rem;}

.scroll-indicator-bar {height: 6px; width: 20%; background-color: #000;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
        <div class="scroll-container" id="scroll-container">
            <ul class="list-inline text-white text-center">
            
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 200px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">1</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 400px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">2</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 300px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">3</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 150px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">4</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 250px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">5</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 300px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">6</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 200px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">7</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 400px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">8</h1></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 300px;">
                    <div class="py-5 bg-dark"><h1 class="py-5">9</h1></div>
                </li>
            
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll-indicator" id="barWrapper">
        <div class="scroll-indicator-bar"  id="myBar"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <button>Prev</button>
        <button>Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

by this code you have a dynamic scrollbar width dynamic width based on the content, and you can manage your own scroll behavior,

then, you can add custom next() and previous() functions to add translate for both scrollbar and content, as implemented in mousemove handler

Comment: Thank you! I will check it. Is there an option to use multiple instances of this on a single page?

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't work: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/yLaZdMP

Comment: it works fine, please try to use the scrollbar itself, (drag it), you still need to add more similar functionality to use Next and Prev buttons

Comment: Thank you! But I try to allow mouse scrolling as well.